# A question on distance between a point whit ${\sigma _\varepsilon }(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

***Definition:***

- $\sigma (A)$ is a set of all eigenvalue of matrix $A$.
- ${\sigma _\varepsilon }(A) = \left\{ {x \in \mathbb{C}:x \in \sigma (A + E),{{\left\| E \right\|}_2} \le \varepsilon } \right\}$

***Now let***

$A \in{M_n}$ and $\varepsilon  > 0$ and $x_0 \notin {\sigma _\varepsilon }(A)$.

Why does $dist({x_0},{\sigma _\varepsilon }(A)) \ge \frac{1}{{{{\left\| {{{(I{x_0} - A)}^{ - 1}}} \right\|}_2}}} - \varepsilon  $?

Comment: Something iffy is going on here, are you sure the inverse of the norm should be there?

Comment: Here's a counterexample.

Take $A = I_2$. Then $\sigma_\varepsilon(A) = [ 1 - \sqrt{\varepsilon}, 1+\sqrt{\varepsilon}]$. Take $x_\delta = \delta + 1 + \sqrt{{\varepsilon}}$. Then $|| Ix_n -A||_2 = \sqrt{2}(\sqrt{\varepsilon} + \delta) \to \sqrt{2\varepsilon}$ as $\delta \to 0$

The conclusion then fails for $\varepsilon = 1/\sqrt{2}$ and the sequence above for sufficiently small $\delta$, as the distance is going to zero, while the RHS increases to $1 - 1/\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @stochasticboy321 - All right. I edited this post